# Scala- How can I read some specific bytes from a file?

Tags: scala

I'd like to encrypt a text(about 1 MB) and I use the max length of RSA keys(4096 bits). However, the key seems too short. As I googled, I got to know that the max size of text that a RSA can encrypt is 8 bytes shorter than the length of the key. Thus, I can only encrypt 501 bytes in this way. So I decided to divide my text into 2093 arrays (1024*1024/501=2092.1).The question is how can I pour the first 501 bytes into the first array in scala?Anyone who can help me this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on whether your cryptographic approach is okay. (I don't know, but would rely on libraries written and vetted by more knowledgeable cryptographers if I were in your shoes. I'm not sure why you choose 501, which is 11 bytes, not 8, shorter than 512.)

But chunking your arrays into fixed-size blocks should be easy. Just use the [grouped](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]) function f Array.

```
val text : String = ???
val bytes = text.getBytes( scala.io.Codec.UTF8.charSet ) // lots of ways to do this
val blocks = bytes.grouped( 501 )
```

Blocks will be an `Iterator[Array[Byte]]`, each 501 bytes long except for the last (which may be shorter).

Comment: Yes，I made a mistake.11 bytes shorter not 8 bytes shorter

Comment: I use "text.toList" and the block is Iterator[List[Char]].The type I want is Array[Byte], do you have any solutions to change the type?

Comment: it's best to go to bytes first as i've shown, because if you've grouped into blocks of 501 chars, there's no guarantee those will turn into 501 bytes on UTF8 decoding (unless you are sure your text is all ASCII). i recommend the approach i've shown above. on the narrow question, can we turn ` Iterator[List[Char]]` into `Iterator[List[Byte]]`, sure. something like `iterListChar.map( _.mkString.getBytes( scala.io.Codec.UTF8.charSet ) )`

Comment: iterListChar.map(_.mkString.getBytes(scala.io.Codec.UTF8.charSet) makes it Iterator [Array[Byte]],what I want is Array[Byte].

Comment: You want a collection of Array[Byte], each 501 long (except the last which might be shorter). That's what `Iterator[Array[Byte]]` is representing for you.